# Orange spots on dry chickpea

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, chickpeas

I have had some dry chickpeas for quite some time (~6-12 months) in my pantry and now I'm looking to cook them.

Most of them have some orange spots, which I'm not sure are normal (See picture below). Are they safe to eat?

[image: 1]

Comment: Are these spots all in the same place on the chickpeas, or are they sort of mottled?  Can you try cracking one in half to see what it looks like on the inside?

Comment: The only orange spot I see on your chickpea is on the embryo, it is normal for it to be differently colored than the rest of the seed, at least in some varieties of bean-related plants. Are there any other spots? can you make a picture with different lighting?

Comment: Sorry, I already cooked them so I couldn't take more pictures. They seemed alright.

Comment: Good grief but that photo looks very, um, explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up cooking the chickpeas and eating them, without any discernible stomach problems